# How does the {,string} syntax work?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I have some hard time understanding the `{,string}` syntax. I mainly use it to rename a files like `mv test{,.original}` But I don't really understand it:

```bsh
echo asdf{,.fdsa}
```

Output:

```
asdf asdf.fdsa
```

But

```bsh
echo asdf{asdf,.fdsa}
```

Output:

```
asdfasdf asdf.fdsa
```

I tried to read through [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) and I found some similar patterns with `#` or `?` but now with `,`. It comes with the idea that this should find patterns but I don't think this is what it does.

how does it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is brace expansion. Read more here about it in the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).

It produces each possibility from the comma separated list in curly brackets.

```
echo asdf{asdf,.fdsa}
asdfasdf asdf.fdsa
```

- `echo` just echoes what's after it (not in each case, but to make things simple, it is in this example)
- `asdf{asdf,.fdsa}` is expanded to two possibilities (as there is one `,` sign so it separates the list into two parts). First of all we've got `asdf` which is the non-changing part, then it is concatenated with another `asdf` (first item from curly brackets list), then space and another `asdf` concatenated with `.fdsa` (the second item listed).

It may be a bit confusing when using the same strings as the prefix and inside the curly brackets, so to make things clearer, let's try:

```
$ echo a{,b,.c,def}gh
agh abgh a.cgh adefgh
```

Which translates into

- `a` + empty string + `gh` = `agh`
- `a` + `b` + `gh` = `abgh`
- `a` + `.c` + `gh` = `a.cgh`
- `a` + `def` + `gh` = `adefgh`